# App activity does not start unless the app is on

Tags: java, android

hope you are sound. So I'm trying to make an app that creates a new alarm activity when the broadcast receiver receives a signal from the alarm manager. For some reason, the activity does not start if the app is in the background or closed. It only works if the app is on. here's my alarm manger -

```
// i'm passing reqCode cause i send multiple alarms        
private void setAlarm(long time, int reqCode) {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, BroadCastManager.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, reqCode, i, 0);
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi);
    }
```

my broadcast receiver -

```
public class BroadCastManager extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // starting alarm screen activity
    Intent alarmScreenIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmScreen.class);
    alarmScreenIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(alarmScreenIntent);
}
```

My manifest -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.ad.nappro">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NapPro"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <receiver android:name="com.ad.nappro.BroadCastManager"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".AlarmScreen"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried to use logcat to check if I'm having any issue with the broadcast manager but don't get any log when I don't have the app on, on my phone.
TIA

Comment: In modern versions of Android, you can't start an Activity from the background, except in specific circumstances.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts for the restrictions on doing so.

Comment: but since i'm sending a pending intent, wouldn't it still pop up at least for a few seconds?